# Python Click application with setuptools integration runs into a python OS error when I try to reproduce the project's venv on other machines

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to allow other computers to also view a simple CLI application that I've put in a virtual environment. After searching for a while, I pip froze and generated a `requirements.txt`. When I attempt to install dependencies on a remote computer via `pip install --editable`. The terminal outputs a Python OS error.

The project is available at https://github.com/JonW27/calc

Screenshots of the error are provided:

[image: here]

I have a strong feeling that I've made a beginner's mistake/ did something dumb. If the post needs clarification then please specify, I honestly don't know what's wrong with it– I made the `venv` relocatable and ran into no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it appears you are attempting to install the package to the python's system-wide location. Try re-creating your virtualenv.